# Can I check US credit score from abroad?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I permanently left the US a few years ago and I am no longer permanent resident.

Is there a way to check my own credit score for personal verification purposes (the major credit agencies require a US address).

Comment: Do you really need your credit score, or are you actually looking to read your credit report and verify that there is nothing incorrect on it?

Comment: [I assume you tried the credit report site?](https://www.annualcreditreport.com/index.action) Can't you just give one of your previous US addresses? That's what the credit agencies will have.

Comment: [Credit Karma](https://www.creditkarma.com/)?

Comment: They all ask for a current US address and I'm not sure it's ok to provide an address I'm not living at. All I need to do is to make sure there is no incorrect information on it.

Comment: @Bob In that case, you don't need your credit score. You simply need a copy of your credit report.

Comment: Do you have a social security number (not an ITIN)?

Comment: I still have a ssn. But I don't think I can get a copy of my credit report without a current US address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Social Security number, you *might* be able to get your credit reports online from the official credit report website, [annualcreditreport.com](https://www.annualcreditreport.com) if your last U.S. address is recent enough.  Fill out the form as if you were still living at your last U.S. address; they are simply using the address to verify your identity with the credit report.  You will get the credit reports online; they won't be sending anything to you by mail.  Remember that there are three credit reporting bureaus that maintain separate credit reports, and you can request all three from that website. Each one does a different lookup, so you might get different responses as to availability. If they cannot fulfill your request online each will provide you with directions on what forms and information needs to be sent to them by mail or a phone number for further info.

If you have trouble doing this online, then you will probably need to request reports by mail, as detailed in [@Michael C.'s answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/79663/10997).

If all you want to do is check for incorrect information, you don't need to obtain a credit score.  Your credit score is based on the information in your credit reports, so if you ensure the accuracy of those reports, the credit score will be based on accurate information.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Experian](http://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/credit-education/faqs/credit-report-faqs/):

> If you are an American citizen living abroad and would like to order a
>   copy of your credit report, send all the following information to
>   Experian, PO Box 2002, Allen, TX 75013.
>
> - Your full name, including middle initial and generation information
> - Your date of birth
> - Your Social Security number
> - Two proofs of your current mailing address (such as a copy of your    driver’s license, utility bill, insurance statement, bank statement
>     or telephone bill that shows your name at your current mailing
>     address)
> - Your previous U.S. address
> - Copy of a government-issued ID card

I would imagine the other credit bureaus are similar if not the same.